# Operator Search Twitter is Not Supported by current product edition Rapidminer 7.1

Tags: rapidminer

I have rapidminer studio 7.1, and I want to try sentiment analysis on twitter, but operator search twiiter cannot used. There is error "Operator is not supported by your current product edition". Anyone can help me?? please..

there is the screenshot : http://prnt.sc/b4z3k0

Comment: my operating system is windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the access to Twitter is a feature of the Professional  RapidMiner version, that is not available in the Basic or Community versions. So you might consider upgrading your license or (if feasible) apply to the academia program for students and academic researchers.
Otherwise the operator works fine in RapidMiner.

Comment: But my friend have I rapidminer studio 7.1 basic version in his os (ubuntu), and the operator twitter search can be used.. 
can you explain this ??

Comment: Probably he is still  in the 14 days trial phase, when you can evaluate professional features.

Comment: yeah you right bro..., my friend have 14 days trial